# Get the global position of a child object in parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I need to get the child's position in global value by using the parents rotation and the child x position. I've tried:
`planet.transform.localPosition`
This gives the position on the x axis but not where it is on the y.

```
        x = planet.transform.position.x * x;

        float y = Mathf.Sin(ring.transform.rotation.z);
        y = planet.transform.position.x * y;

        Vector2 position = new Vector3(x, y);
```

This doesn't get the proper position, it is off by quite a bit

```
transform.TransformPoint(planet.transform.position))
```

This did not work at all, it was off by far.

Then i tried instantiating an object and having it at 0,0,0 and have its rotation to the ring rotation and move transform.up to the planet position on the x.

Am i doing anything wrong here?

(The planets only use the X axis and rely on the parent "ring"'s rotation to change the position)

[image: Diagram]

The diagram on the left shows that the parent rotation is 0, and the child position is 0,10,0. The right diagram shows the parent's rotation is 45, but the child's position is unknown. What would it be and how would you work it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child's `transform.position` IS the global position. If you're trying to use the child's LOCAL x-position (i.e., relative to its parent) then you would want to use `transform.localPosition`.

But again, no need to step through any transform math, just grab the world position directly with `transform.position`.

:EDIT:

Here's a script I wrote. All it does is get the parent's rotation angles, if they exist, and show those along with the `transform.localPosition` and `transform.position` values.

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        string positionString = "";
        if (transform.parent != null)
        {
            positionString += "Parent rotation: <" +
                              transform.parent.localEulerAngles.x + ", " +
                              transform.parent.localEulerAngles.y + ", " +
                              transform.parent.localEulerAngles.z + ">; ";
        }

        positionString += "Child Local Position: <" +
                          transform.localPosition.x + ", " +
                          transform.localPosition.y + ", " +
                          transform.localPosition.z + ">; ";

        positionString += "Child World Position: <" +
                          transform.position.x + ", " +
                          transform.position.y + ", " +
                          transform.position.z + ">; ";
        Debug.Log(positionString);
    }
}
```

Here's the output of the script. You can see the debug messages in the log there showing the rotation angles of the parent and the child's local position and the world position. I wiggle it by hand for a bit then I go through the 30, 45, 60, and 90 degree angles because those are common angles to memorize for trig functions: 0.5, sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(3)/2, etc. Note the radius (local position) is 5, so it's 5x those values.

If this still doesn't get you what you need then I need you to work through the math by hand for an example problem to show what exactly you're looking for that's different.

[image: world_position]

Comment: But this doesn't give the position it is, it just gives the position of the child INSIDE the parent, I'm trying to get the position of it with the parent's rotation. So parent rotation is 10 on the z, and the child's x is 5 if i do Debug.Log(transform.position) on the child it just gives 5, not the space it would be outside the parent. You get what I'm saying?

Comment: @Jerry post your case in post , parent transfrom all value , and child transfrom all value.

Comment: @Jerry no I don't understand what you're saying. The position in the Editor inspector window is the localPosition. If you want that value programmatically, that's what you call it. If you want the world position that's always`transform.position`. I would urge you to try it.

Comment: @Chuck I've added more of an explanation to the question. Sorry if it doesn't help anymore than previous

Comment: @Jerry - Added more content there.

Comment: This answer works very well thankyou!

Comment: :D sorry my explanation wasn't very good first up, did the diagram help?

Comment: @Jerry - Diagram helped convince me to make the GIF and demo script for you, but I *was* suggesting `transform.position` from the start :P

Comment: oh you added a GIF? i can't see images :(
i only see the world position, but your text response helped me :D

Comment: @Jerry https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFIX5.gif

Comment: i can't access that either sadly, i'm on a school laptop :') they are lovely